Code39 full ascii
I'm trying to configure a barcode code39 full ascii, it seems to work ok except for the char #, I've tried font libre barcode code 39, azalea font and barcode 39, all with the same result. When headed the # is showed as £. Maybe it's the default keyboard layout but didn't know how to force another only for the barcode scanner and not the keyboard (win 10)
Thanks

If you look at the definition the symbol "£" is not even defined for Code39.  It must be your scanner that is set for incorrect keyboard translation.

It was both scanner and pc settings, to have the # both have to be set in US (barcode scanner settings and windows keyboard).
